# SwiftUI does not reliably propagate changes to child view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

I am observing a peculiar behavior in my SwiftUI code and narrowed it down to the following minimal example.

Given this example storage holding an array of book model structs.

```swift
struct Book: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID
    var likes: Int
    var unusedProperty: String = ""
}

extension Book: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Book, rhs: Book) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

class MyStorage: ObservableObject {

    @Published var books: [Book] = [
        .init(id: .init(uuidString: "B2A44450-BC03-47E6-85BE-E89EA69AF5AD")!, likes: 0),
        .init(id: .init(uuidString: "F5AB9D18-DF73-433E-BB48-1C757CB6F8A7")!, likes: 0)
    ]

    func addLike(to book: Book) {
        for i in books.indices where books[i].id == book.id {
            books[i].likes += 1
        }
    }
}
```

And using it in this simple view hierarchy:

```swift
struct ReducedContentView: View {
    @StateObject var storage: MyStorage = MyStorage()

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            ForEach(storage.books) { book in
                HStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Top-Level: \(book.likes)")
                        BookView(book: book)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Add Like") {
                        storage.addLike(to: book)
                    }
                }.padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BookView: View {
    let book: Book

    var body: some View {
        Text("Nested: \(book.likes)")
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

Any changes to the `likes` property don't propagate to the `BookView`, only to the "top-level" `Text`.

[image]

Now, **if I change one of the following**, it works:

- remove the `unusedProperty` (which is needed in production)
- add `&& lhs.likes == rhs.likes` to the Equatable conformance (which is not intended)
- modify `BookView` to accept `@Binding var book: Book` instead of a `let`

The last option is something I could adopt in my production code - nevertheless, I would really like to understand what's happening here, so any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a result of your custom `Equatable` conformance:

```
extension Book: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Book, rhs: Book) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

If you remove this, it'll work as expected.

In your current code, you're saying that if two `Book`s have the same ID, they are *equal*. My suspicion is that you don't actually mean that they are truly equal -- you just mean that they are *the same book*.

Your second option ("add `&& lhs.likes == rhs.likes` to the `Equatable` conformance (which is not intended)") essentially just uses the synthesized `Equatable` conformance that the system generates, since `unusedProperty` isn't used -- so, if you were to use the second option, you may as well just remove the custom `==` function altogether.

I think the decision to make here is whether you really want to tell the system an untruth (that two `Book`s, no matter what their other properties, are *equal* if they share the same `id`) or if you should let the system do it's own work telling if the items are equal or not.

Comment: You're spot-on, @jnpdx. Another part of my code relied on this custom "interpretation" of equality and you're right - that's probably an untruth. I suspect by doing this, I interfere with SwiftUIs diffing, which causes the observed effect. Thanks a lot! :)